# Blazor release build Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException

Tags: blazor, release

I'm trying to get Release build of Blazor WebAssembly project, but I always get Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException exception. It doesn't work with sample Microsoft project:

```
> dotnet new blazorwasm -o WebApplication1 --hosted

The template "Blazor WebAssembly App" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on WebApplication1\WebApplication1.sln...
  Restore completed in 186.56 ms for C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Shared\WebApplication1.Shared.csproj.
  Restore completed in 270.86 ms for C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Server\WebApplication1.Server.csproj.
  Restore completed in 270.86 ms for C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj.

Restore succeeded.

> dotnet build WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj --configuration Release

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0-preview-19565-02+2f706bcd0 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 29.32 ms for C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Shared\WebApplication1.Shared.csproj.
  Restore completed in 37.98 ms for C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj.
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  WebApplication1.Shared -> C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Shared\bin\Release\netstandard2.1\WebApplication1.Shared.dll
  Fatal error in Mono IL Linker
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : Unhandled exception. Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'obj\Release\netstandard2.1\WebApplication1.Client.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
   ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'obj\Release\netstandard2.1\WebApplication1.Client.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
     at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
     at Mono.Linker.AssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
     at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve(IMetadataScope scope)
     at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve(IMetadataScope scope)
     at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve(String name)
     at Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromAssemblyStep.Process()
     at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process(LinkContext context)
     at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
     at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
     at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run(ILogger customLogger)
     at Mono.Linker.Driver.Execute(String[] args, ILogger customLogger)
     at Mono.Linker.Driver.Main(String[] args)
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : ILLink failed with exit code -532462766. [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : Unhandled exception. Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'obj\Release\netstandard2.1\WebApplication1.Client.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : ILLink failed with exit code -532462766. [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

BlazorApp1.Client.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\BlazorApp1.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've searched for this error, and it happened to be a popular one, lot of crosslinks between stackoverflow - asp.net github - mono github. The only solution to it, which is applicable in my situation is disable linker by adding `<BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>` in project file. But it doesn't help, it gives me following error with it:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0-preview-19565-02+2f706bcd0 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 29.64 ms for C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Shared\WebApplication1.Shared.csproj.
  Restore completed in 36.85 ms for C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj.
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  WebApplication1.Shared -> C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Shared\bin\Release\netstandard2.1\WebApplication1.Shared.dll
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolveBlazorRuntimeDependencies" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\obj\Release\netstandard2.1\WebApplication1.Client.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\obj\Release\netstandard2.1\WebApplication1.Client.dll' [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nGetFileInformation(String s) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build.ResolveBlazorRuntimeDependencies.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyPath) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build.ResolveBlazorRuntimeDependencies.ResolveRuntimeDependenciesCore(String entryPoint, IEnumerable`1 applicationDependencies, IEnumerable`1 monoBclAssemblies) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build.ResolveBlazorRuntimeDependencies.Execute() [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolveBlazorRuntimeDependencies" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\obj\Release\netstandard2.1\WebApplication1.Client.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\obj\Release\netstandard2.1\WebApplication1.Client.dll' [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nGetFileInformation(String s) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build.ResolveBlazorRuntimeDependencies.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyPath) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build.ResolveBlazorRuntimeDependencies.ResolveRuntimeDependenciesCore(String entryPoint, IEnumerable`1 applicationDependencies, IEnumerable`1 monoBclAssemblies) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build.ResolveBlazorRuntimeDependencies.Execute() [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
C:\Users\apetrov\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(376,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\Users\apetrov\source\repos\BlazorTest\WebApplication1\Client\WebApplication1.Client.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

**How to make it compilable in Release configuration?**

Additional information:

```
> dotnet --version
5.0.100-alpha1-015766

> dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.100-alpha1-015766
 Commit:    b81ee62da5

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-alpha1-015766\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.0-alpha.1.19564.1
  Commit:  c77948d92a

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.100-preview3-014645 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.100-alpha1-015766 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0-preview3.19555.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0-alpha1.19577.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0-preview3.19553.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0-alpha.1.19564.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0-preview3.19553.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0-alpha.1.19564.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: what does `dotnet --version` return?

Comment: I have added `dotnet --version` and `dotnet --info` in question.

Comment: You are using a custom build of .net5? I don't recognize that alpha. But your template is not the .net5 template. You either need a global.json to fix your runtime to 3.1.402 or you need to update your template

Comment: global.json didn't help for some reason, but uninstalling 5.0 sdk helped. Many thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gratitude to [Mister Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658697/mister-magoo) for the hint.

It looks like SDK 5.0 preview interferes it in some way. I've tried to add global.json file with following content:

```
{
    "sdk": {
      "version": "3.1.402"
    }
}
```

but it didn't help. Then I uninstalled .NET Core SDK 5.0.0-preview and now it compiles.